# How to create a custom height TextFormField in flutter?

Tags: flutter, textformfield

I have a form where there are two **TextFormField** and one bottom button to validate it but the problem is that the screen is looking awkward. I want the **TextFormField ** the bottom one two cove the area between them completely even if there is no content and become scrollable once it reaches the bottom.[image]

the left one is what I have, but I want the right one, I tried to wrap it with **Expandable** or **Container** but it didn't work because I was using border property.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by wrapping the `TexFormField` widget with an `Expanded` widget and setting the `expands` and `maxLines` property of the `TextFormField` to `true` and `null` respectively.

The `TextFormField` with take all the available space irrespective of the screen size, check the code provided below for an example:

```
  // wrap it with an Expanded widget
         Expanded(
           child: TextFormField(
             // set the keyboard type to multiline f
             keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
             // set maxlines to null
             maxLines: null,
             // set expands to true
             expands: true,
             decoration: InputDecoration(
                 isDense: true,
                 border: OutlineInputBorder(
                     borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black)
                 )
             ),
           ),
         ),
```

Answer (score 2):

You just have to increase the `maxLines` inside the `TextFormField` to increase it's size like this:

```
Container(
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.5,//set the size according to your choice
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    //Customize your container
    color: Colors.red,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
  ),
  child: TextFormField(
    maxLines: 30,//add any number of lines
    //Customize your text field
  )
),
```

Comment: What if there is 5 inch and 6 inch device how will it work with same value of maxLines because I want to cover the entire area.

Comment: You can wrap it inside a `Container` with provided `height` as `MediaQuery`. I am editing my code

Comment: You can check the code now. And do tell me if you need any other help in this code.

Comment: This is not a better approach of addressing the question, the height set will vary for different devices @HardikKumar. The question asked for the `TextFormField` to cover all the available space on the screen.